# Force OS X app to use particular libcurl.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, libcurl, dylib

My app requires Version 7 of libcurl, and works fine on Lion, but the version of libcurl.dylib on Snow Leopard doesn't work (I need the * prefix to my *MKD commands).

I tried various ways to include the Lion version of libcurl.dylib in my package, including putting a copy in (1) the app folder, (2) the Contents folder, (3) the MacOS folder, and (4) the Resources folder, with no success. Even four copies, one in each folder. (Still goes to /usr/lib.)

I also tried setting the "Runpath Search Paths" in Xcode 4.2 to ".", but that didn't help.

So, question #1 is, how can I force my app on Snow Leopard to use the dylib I include in the package? (Installing a new libcurl.dylib is out of the question--this app is going to the Mac App Store.)

Experimentally, I replaced /usr/lib/libcurl.dylib on my Snow Leopard system with the file from Lion, and with that the app worked. So I know that if I can get the app to use this library, it will work OK.

I also tried building a static libcurl.a, which worked (using configure, make, and make install), but in attempting to link with that the app still referenced the dylib. I then changed that name of the static library, to libcurl-static.a, but then there were linker errors, as dozens of symbols were undefined from other dylibs. I attempted to include more dylibs in my build, to get these resolved, but the list of dylibs needed by libcurl is apparently long. I tried to use otool to find out what was required, but none of the options showed me anything useful.

Question #2 is: How to I link my app with libcurl statically?

(I have a workaround for not being able to use *MKD, which ignores the error if the directory already exists, but it involves too many extra FTP operations and is inefficient. My approach with *MKD works fine, and is fast.)

No need suggesting that I go to another FTP library, as I've already thought of that. Don't really want to, as libcurl is working fine on Lion. If only I could get it to use the library I ship on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to change the ID of the library (before linking) - by default it will point to `/usr/lib/` which is not where you are shipping it. See the `otool -L`:

```
$ otool -L /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib  | head -n 2
/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
```

To change the ID you use `install_name_tool -id new/path/libcurl.4.dylib your/copy/of/libcurl.4.dylib`, in particular you probably want to use the `@executable_path/` prefix which corresponds to the location of your executable. Alternatively you can change the path in your compiled binary with `install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib @executable_path/libcurl.4.dylib yourapp`

2) You force static linking by using the library name so instead of `-lcurl` you simply use `libcurl.a` (with the full path if it is not in the current directory) - I would highly recommend that path, it causes fewer headaches.

PS: I'm not sure whether you can legally ship Apple's libcurl (you may, I don't know) - but it's very easy to compile it from Apple's sources directly for SL which avoids any Lion issues.

Comment: Thanks very much for #1. For #2, my question wasn't about how to get libcurl.a in there, it was about how to get all the referenced libraries to be resolved.

I decided the libcurl approach wasn't what I wanted to go with anyway. Switched the code over to CFFTP, and it's now working very well on 10.6 and 10.7.

Comment: Dependencies are resolved by listing them - there is no implicit dependency resolution, only explicit. It's usually no problem as that is typically done either at configure time or via self-reporting like `pkgconfig`.